# How to target the div tag attributes separably

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a very interesting work here, I am working on it and it is very interesting but some time such kind of issue wast our time and we get confuse.
The simple thing that I want to achieve is that.
Product Name
44 Euro 30 Euro with sale red line
Add to cart button
I simple I want to display the both pries in single like.

**HTML**

```
 <div class="product-Detail">
<h4>Product Name</h4>
<p>79.00 &#163;</p>
<p style="color:#F16161; text-decoration:line-through;">59.00 &#163;</p>
<p>
<a href="#" class="btn btn-info">ADD TO CART</a>
</p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
 h4 {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

.product-Detail {
    width: 250px;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.product-Detail p {
    font-size: 14px;
    display: inline;
}
```

Comment: http://jsbin.com/cecoyuna/1/edit I can see the price is inline

Comment: The pries is inline but, the button is also inline. I want strong css to move the a link to second line.

Comment: try this http://jsfiddle.net/U5Tfp/2/

Comment: check the updated DEMO http://jsbin.com/cecoyuna/1/edit. As `p` element is defined as inline. so for `add to cart` button again used `display:block;`

Comment: hhh sorry Reading your question cracked me up ;]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As in your code all `p` tag are inline that's why The button is also aligned.

you can break it by giving `display:block` on `a` tag. check the **[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/cecoyuna/1/edit)**.

```
.product-Detail p a.btn{display:block;} /*Responsible for making a tag as block level element*/
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<p style="display:block">
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-info">ADD TO CART</a>
</p>
```

Or

```
.product-Detail .btn{
    display:block; 
}
```

Now your link will be on another line.

Comment: check css posted by OP.

Comment: CSS is not right still. you need a gap between classes to effect.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty clean CSS to target the 3rd `<p>`

```
.product-Detail p:nth-of-type(3) {
    display: block;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/U5Tfp/3/

Comment: why you are making it so complex; when the result could achieve just simple line of code.

Comment: OP wanted to target the `<p>` element, not the `<a>`

Comment: OP simply want the button in next line.

Comment: That would be poor design in this model.